# Aplicação para quando passo uma List por parametro para um Sub relatório

Tags: java, jasper-reports, relatório

Estou tentando passar uma Lista por parâmetro para meu Sub Relatório, porém quando chega em determinada parte a aplicação para e o relatório não é gerado. Nunca sai disso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou passando a Lista dessa forma:

```
public boolean gerarRelatorio(List list, int numeroRelatorio, String nomePrestador, String dataSistema) {
    JasperReport report = null;
    InputStream image = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/LOGO.png");
    filtro.put("Image", image);

    filtro.put("listaDados", listaProcedimentos);
    filtro.put("localizarRel", "src/br/com/xml/relatorio/subRelatorio.jasper");

    try {

        InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/Relatorio3.jrxml");
        report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamReal);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao pegar arquivos!", "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    try {

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, filtro, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                "C:/Demonstrativos/" + dataSistema + "/" + nomePrestador + "_" + dataSistema + "_" + numeroRelatorio + ".pdf");

        return true;

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao Gerar relatório, verifique se nenhum arquivo está aberto ou se o nome está correto!\n" + ex, "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe o porquê da aplicação parar sem nenhum erro?

Answer (score 1):

Cara, isso normalmente não dá muito certo, trabalho já tem um tempinho com o jasper e ele é bem encrencado pra essas partes de passagem de parâmetro, principalmente para objetos, a dica que vou te dar é a seguinte, lá no jasperreports(aconselho utilizar a 5.6), no relatório principal você cria um parâmetro do tipo list com o mesmo nome desse que você esta mandando pra ele. Na hora de que você for configurar o subreport, onde você passa o diretório, creio que por parâmetro também, você passa o seguinte na opção "Data Source Expression" "new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaDados)". Neste caso, "listaDados" é o parâmetro que você criou. Lembra de que tem que ser idêntico ao que você esta mandando no código. Qualquer coisa eu posso montar um tutorialzinho. Espero ter ajudado. Abraço!